# The dist folder contain only assets folder after running ng build --configuration=production

Tags: angular, azure, visual-studio-code, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I am beginner in azure and I want to deploy an angular application to azure with Visual Studio Code, so I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_CRppLcC9k which is really helpful but after running `ng build --configuration=production` a dist folder is generated but it contains only assets folder with images and some js files.

[image]

Normally I should choose dist/appname to deploy it in Visual Studio Code using azure extension but my appame is not exist under dist folder.

Does anyone know what's happening ?

PS : The build is successful

Note : I cannot see the dist file in the file explorer

Comment: Do you have a property called `projects` in **angular.josn**?

Comment: Is your app running successfully after deployment?

Comment: @BennyHalperin yes I have

Comment: @Harshitha yes it runs successfully

Comment: @Hiba - Check the below answer and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Iam able to see the Appname in the `dist` folder.

It seems that you have missed the steps to create a .NET Core Web App.

***Check the below workaround to create a .NET App with Angular and deploy to Azure App Service.***

In Visual Studio, Create a new `.NET Core API` with .NET 6.0 LTS.

[image]

- Open the .NET Core API in VSCode => Right click on AppName => click on  `Open in Integrated Terminal` .

[image]

- Create a new `ClientApp` (This is the one which you have missed and that is the reason you cannot see the `AppName` in dist Folder

Run the below commands to create and angular app.

```cs
ng n ClientApp
yes
Select css
```

[image]

- ClientApp1 with Angular configuration will be created.

[image]
[image]

- Select the newly created `ClientApp`  => `Open in Integrated Terminal`.

[image])

- Now run `ng build`.
  [image]
- `dist` folder is created and you can see that it has ClientApp1(AppName).

[image]

[image]

Continue with the next steps from the link which you have shared to deploy the App to Azure App Service.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I have to modify the "outputPath" in the file angular.json from `"outputPath": "dist"` to `"outputPath": "dist/appname"` .

This is how it works for me.